# Dynamically generate filter condition in DataWeave

Tags: filter, dataweave

Is it possible to generate a filter condition dynamically in DW based on input values?

Something like this

```
payload.entries filter ((item, index) -> dynamicallyGeneratedFilterCondition )
```

where `dynamicallyGeneratedFilterCondition` is a variable defined for example like this

```
var dynamicallyGeneratedFilterCondition = "item.price == 10"
```

Answer (score 1):

`filter` is "dynamic" by definition because the 2nd argument is a lambda-expression (aka anonymous function) that is created and provided to `filter` with every application.

Now based upon your code snippets on whether you can refactor the expression so it appears as a separate declaration, the answer is, yes you can:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var fn = (v) -> v > 5
---
{
    call1: 1 to 10 filter $ > 5,
    call2: 1 to 10 filter fn($)
}
```