# Using a declared function vs an inline lambda-expression

Tags: dataweave

Motivated by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67640801/dynamically-generate-filter-condition-in-dataweave) and based on the signature of `filter` from [this documentation page](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dw-core-functions-filter) can you explain why the following DW expression fails:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var fn = <T>(v:T,i:Number): Boolean -> v > 5
---
1 to 10 filter fn
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to me like a collision with the infix notation pre-processing, which automatically creates an anonymous function with the `$` signs. That is why `fn($)` works; the preprocessing that creates this doesn't seem smart enough to recognize when the right hand side is a function reference.. which seems like a bad thing given function should be first class...

Works fine using prefix notation..

This works:

`filter(1 to 10, fn)`

So this *should* work:

`(1 to 10) filter fn`

But the pre-processing is automatically wrapping it in an anonymous function even though you're already passing in a function with the correct signature.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Michaell Jones answer, note that a Range is not an Array, but it is auto coerced. I used a function instead of a closure variable and got away with just a warning about the auto coercion:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

fun fn<T>(v:T,i:Number): Boolean = v > 5
---
1 to 10 filter fn($,$$)
```

Comment: `fun` is preprocessed as well, it makes sense, ty aled!

Comment: The point is that you should be able to make the right JUST `fn`, but good to know this doesn't care if you use `fun` or `var`

Comment: Functions seems to be just named closures, so it makes sense that they work in the same way.

Comment: Keep in mind the expression in the original post should work.  So there seems to be a minor bug in the DW preprocessor.  I hope we are all in agreement here.

Comment: ... and I just realized you apply the function by passing the `$,$$` as args aled.  The whole point is to use the function as a value which is what `filter` expects and not invoke it.

Comment: Please add that expectation to the question.